# How to share node_modules and package.json files between two directories?

Tags: wordpress, node-modules, package.json, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

As I experiment with WordPress's new Gutenberg development methods, I noticed that I need to create individual block folders within the plugins directory. These are essentially the components that makeup the front-end and editor side of things.

I would like to understand two things:

1. How to install `node_modules` and `package.json` files so that commands are accepted when not in a specific block directory folder.
2. I would like to run certain builds with specific scripts, what are the proper commands to hand this procedure when outside of a block directory?

How do I setup my environment so that when I type in a command, it understand to compile no matter which plugin directory I am in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [create-block package](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-create-block/) has scaffolding that allows you to create blocks and [the package is undergoing heavy development right now](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/25188) that will allow you to have multiple blocks within one folder.